# How to copy the file and overwrite the existing one

Tags: c#, file, copy

I have two buttons called *Load* and *New*. First you have to *Load* the file. Then when you click the *New* button it must copy the file you loaded, overwrite it, and modify the last modified date as well. How can I do that? I tried the code below and nothing happens.

The code I have under the *New* button to copy a file:

```
FileInfo originalfile = new FileInfo(PathSelection); 
FileInfo newfile = new FileInfo(PathSelection);
```

Comment: [Copy File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)... Pretty much first result for "c# copy file"

Comment: The code you have provided doesn't copy anything.  All it does it loads an instance of the file into a `FileInfo` object and exposes it's metadata.  The [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class pretty much tells you everything you need to do.

Answer (score 6):

I didn't quite understand your question, but copying and replacing a file is like the code below.

```
FileInfo Sourcefile = new FileInfo(Sourcepath);
Sourcefile.CopyTo(Destpath, true);
```

[FileInfo.CopyTo Method (String, Boolean)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5axsfwbc(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Copies an existing file to a new file, allowing the overwriting of an
>   existing file.

```
public FileInfo CopyTo(
    string destFileName,
    bool overwrite
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
private FileInfo sourceFile;

private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sourceFile = new FileInfo(tbSourceFile.Text);
}

private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sourceFile.CopyTo(tbDestFile.Text);
}
```

Comment: from the first button, you load the file and it loaded the file on gridview. now,i want to click new button and the file that was load must get copied to the gridview for new button. now can i do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you want to copy a file to a gridview?  Can you expand on this a bit more?

Comment: I have used your example on new button with a bit of modifications. am gonna mark it as answer..